com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
So I am using firebase stroage to stream m3u8 file, and need to play this in the exo player. But unfortunately the video is not playing and giving the error mentioned below
Playback error
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:684)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:656)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:419)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:90)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:105)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:68)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:179)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:420)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Below Is my firebase Storage rules
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

And this is my cloud Firestore rules
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {

      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 8, 8);
        }
      }
    }

Below is my composable class which is playing the video
fun ExoPlayerRemote(
    videoUrl: String,  // URL from Firebase Storage
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Obtain Firebase Auth token
    var authToken by remember {
        mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        user?.getIdToken(true)?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                authToken = task.result?.token
            } else {
                // Handle the case where obtaining the token failed
                Log.e("FirebaseAuth", "Failed to obtain auth token", task.exception)
            }
        }
    }

    val exoPlayer = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
    }

    // Update the dataSourceFactory when the authToken is available
    LaunchedEffect(authToken) {
        if (authToken != null) {
            val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().apply {
                // Properly set the authorization header using the available method
                setDefaultRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer $authToken")
            }
            
            val mediaSource: MediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(videoUrl)))

            exoPlayer.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
            exoPlayer.prepare()
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
        }
    }

    AndroidView(
        factory = { ctx ->
            PlayerView(ctx).apply {
                player = exoPlayer
            }
        },
        modifier = modifier
    )

    DisposableEffect(exoPlayer) {
        onDispose {
            exoPlayer.release()
        }
    }
}

As you can see I am using the firebase token to fetch the video, but still facing 403.
What I have tried

Running the same m3u8 locally and it is working as expected.
Remove authentication from the firebase rules, after doing this I am
getting 404.
After removing authentication I tried to run the video
by copy/pasting the video url directly from the firestore.
video url is https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/abc.appspot.com/o/index%2Fpage%20line%2Fabcd%2Fmaster.m3u8?alt=media&token=45617efb-0181-493a-ade6-b4624671bcc3(Due to privacy this url is edited).
Any help is greatly appreciated.

